# Hibernate implementation of simple many-to-many relationships - Dictionary or List?

Tags: c#, performance, nhibernate

I have 3 DB Tables: Person, Address, and PersonAddress. Person Address is a simple join table (only stores the IDs of Person and Address).

In my domain model, I have Person and Address. Person is configured to have a many-to-many relationship to Address (through PersonAddress). In code, this is implemented with `List<Address>`.

I've been told that I will get better performance from nHibernate if I...

1. Create a PersonAddress domain object
2. Configure Person to have a one-to-many relationship to PersonAddress
3. Configure a a many-to-many index for Address on this relationship
4. Implement it in code with a `Dictionary<Address, PersonAddress>`

Is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't create an unnecessary class in the domain just because of that. The use of a dictionary for better performance also sounds weird to me.

You could use an [idbag](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-6/1nr4enxv3dpeq/9#6(2E)7(2E)(C2)(A0)Using_an_(3C)idbag(3E)), this is faster to update. (This is mapped as a List in the domain, but has an id in the database).

There are always different things to consider about performance. There is a very interesting chapter in the reference documentation [about collection performance](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-16/1nr4enxv3dpeq/19#16(2E)5(2E)(C2)(A0)Understanding_Collection_performance).

Answer (score 1):

I also would not introduce a complex mapping for the sakes of performance in NHibernate until the need for doing so is established.

Along with the standard many-to-many mapping you can use the a one-to-many strategy with the PersonAddress object (PersonAddress has a collection of Persons and a collection of Addresses). This strategy is used when you want to maintain additional information about the Person-Address relationship.